# How would you create a layout table like the following example in SSRS?

Tags: layout, reporting-services, matrix

I'm looking to create a report like this...

```
Joe Smith
Attr 1 - a    Attr 4 - d
Attr 2 - b    Attr 5 - e
Attr 3 - c    Attr 6 - f
```

... where the 6 attributes for the given item are shown like this.

Should I use a matrix?

Can a matrix be used like that?

Or is there something better that is more related to the layout than the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both of you, but what I was looking for, based on my own ignorance of SSRS, was the List control.

I'm sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd insert the values into a temporary table and assign them a row number. Then I'd join the temporary table onto itself returning half the values in one column and the other half of the values in another column:

```
DECLARE @RowCount int

DECLARE @Items TABLE (
    Name nvarchar,
    RowNumber int
)

INSERT INTO @Items
SELECT      Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
FROM        SomeTable

SET @RowCount = CEILING((@@ROWCOUNT + 1) / 2)

SELECT          I1.Name LeftName,
                I2.Name RightName
FROM            @Items I1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Items I2 ON I2.RowNumber = (I1.RowNumber + @RowCount)
WHERE           I1.RowNumber <= @RowCount
```

Comment: I couldn't verify, but I'm sure this was a good solution, too, in general. (Which means my question probably wasn't specific enough.) In my case, I was getting my data from a SharePoint connection, so I don't think temp tables would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

IS the number of attributes per item constant? Right now, does your data set return these attributes as separate fields (columns) or records (rows)?

If they are already returned as separate fields, then I would add additional data group rows to the table: three additional rows for the example you gave. The cell containing "Joe Smith" could be merged to cover a few columns.

If you layout the table this way in SSRS and return the fields as different columns, then your export to .csv will look a lot nicer than weenoid's solution.

Comment: This is a better solution than weenoid's, in my case, as what I was looking for was a way to change the layout that was more internal to SSRS and less about the data. I ended up using the list view (see my own answer to the question), but this solution would have been just as good.